# Get Default NumberFormat for Currency based on User Language

Tags: c#, excel, format, currency

I developed a Excel add-on so that users can insert some numbers from server to their worksheets. Now I am trying to format cells with inserted data.
Because my users belong to various countries, 
the add-on should format based on their culture.

- Some use period as decimal separator, some use comma.
- Some use comma as thousand separator, some use blank or period.
- Some use fraction currency, some not.

Now I use NumberFormatInfo class and generate NumberFormat string manually.
Here is the code:

```
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    StringBuilder sbFormat = new StringBuilder();
    sbFormat.Append("#");
    if (nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator == "?")
        sbFormat.Append(" ");
    else
        sbFormat.Append(nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator);
    sbFormat.Append("##0");
    if (nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits > 0)
    {
        sbFormat.Append(nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
        sbFormat.Append(new string('0', nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits));
    }
    cell.NumberFormat = sbFormat.ToString();
```

I have no idea this code covers all patterns or not.
Hoping to use something that Excel provides as default, but I could not find that.

Any idea?

Thanks!